# $location service and URLs for links

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular directive that shows paging links for search results. My current implementation for the page links is with events...

For example:

```
$scope.goToNextPage = function() {
  if ($scope.pageIndex < $scope.maxPage()) {
    $scope.pageIndex = $scope.pageIndex + 1;
  }
};
```

I want to change this to use the $location service so that the paging links operate as actual links... i.e. an anchor with href attribute and all the usual behavior.

So the HTML would look something like this:

```
<a href="?pageIndex=2">Page 2</a>
```

My problem is how to handle the case where there is already a URL search value that the directive doesn't care about, and cannot affect.

For example, if the URL is `/search?customerId=23&pageIndex=1`, the URL for page 2 needs to be `/search?customerId=23&pageIndex=2`. But the directive doesn't know or care about customerId...

Doing this in code would look something like:

```
$location.search({pageIndex: 2});
```

But since I am using anchors, I need to know what the URL to put into the HREF will be.

Are there any options or solutions I am missing?

Essentially, I need to **peek** at the URL that would result from calling  `$location.search({pageIndex: 2})`

Comment: You haven't shown us what exactly your directive looks like. Have you tried going through the example from Angular wiki (http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/11/).

Comment: Sorry I should have posted more code. However, my implementation is just like that JsFiddle. Specifically, my anchors have an ng-click directive set to a method on $scope. E.g. $scope.nextPage()

What I am looking to do is remove the ng-click and replace it with an href containing the pageIndex and anything else that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a function for this. Something like:

```
$scope.goToPage = function (pageNum) {
    $location.search({pageIndex: pageNum});
}
```

If you go with this method, use it on ngClick rather than as an href.

Another option would be to stringify the url parameters. This would require a jQuery function:

```
<a ng-href="?{{pagingQueryString(2)}}">Page 2</a>
```

Controller function:

```
$scope.pagingQueryString = function (pageNum) {
    var queryObject = angular.extend($location.search(), {pageIndex: pageNum});

    // jquery function to stringify the object to url
    return $.param(queryObject);
}
```

You could also wrap it all up in a filter:

```
app.filter('pagingQueryString', function ($location) {
    return function (pageNum) {
        var queryObject = angular.extend({}, $location.search(), {pageIndex: pageNum});

        // jquery function to stringify the object to url
        return '?' + $.param(queryObject);
    }
}
```

HTML could then be:

```
<a ng-href="{{2 | pagingQueryString}}">Page 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did write something similar, but was hoping I didn't need it :). I do like the filter idea, though I'm curious if that is not "proper" use of filters? Aren't they  more for visual formatting?

Comment: They can be used for a lot of things. Think about the standard "filter" filter: model.myArray | filter: searchText. This is going in and filtering and limiting the entire array, thus probably changing the UI as you may be iterating over it in an ngRepeat. So they can be more than just visual changes like the "currency" or "number" filters.

Comment: As a note, using the filter or the function methods can have performance implications the more you use them. The filter or function will be run for every $digest cycle. Using ngClick will resolve that issue as it will only be run when clicking the item. If you really need proper href's, you might want to do a one-way binding which is available in the watch-fighters directives here: https://github.com/abourget/abourget-angular

Comment: Maybe I could be talked out of proper hrefs. My big thing is I like web sites to be consistent in how they work. For example, an anchor to have an href, not run some JS. It might not be a huge deal for some people, but I just think an anchor should be an anchor.

Comment: Makes sense. The performance hit on the solutions above would be very minimal, and you could eliminate it with the $watch-fighters directives (or a similar directive), which would allow you to keep your hrefs (also better for search engines if you're exposed to the outside world).

Comment: I'm leaning towards the pagingQueryString method approach. One small issue with the code is the third line should be `var queryObject = angular.extend({}, $location.search(), {pageIndex: pageNum});`. Otherwise it is modifying $location.search().